# Getting text from internet

Tags: java, android, text

If you go to http://www.elven.ee/ip/ - you can see it gives ip. If you refresh, it gives different port.

How can I get that IP into android? I don't know how to make it also update after like every 5 seconds, but right now I want to know how can i get it into my phone. I want to display it as TextView :).

Comment: it is always the same **IP** for me. Only the number after the `;` changes on each call, but that is not part of the **IP** (maybe a port number?)

Comment: Oh yes, that is what I meant, that port changes :). My mistake. Now I only need to find out how the hell I can do loop :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mopsled solution did not work for me, so here is mine:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String ip = "";
    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.elven.ee/ip/");
    try {
        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            ip = getString(response);
        }
    } catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tv.setText(ip);
}

private static String getString(HttpResponse response) {
    final HttpEntity retEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (retEntity != null) {
        InputStream instream = null;
        try {
            instream = retEntity.getContent();
        } catch (final IllegalStateException ise) {
            ise.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
        return result;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

private static String convertStreamToString(final InputStream is) {
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest file.

Comment: Whoa, it worked! Thank you very much :)! I need to now inspect it properly to understand it as well :D!

Comment: do you know how to set it to refresh after every 5 seconds as well :/?

Comment: @Elven you can find a good tutorial on Timers in the android developers resources: [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Fixed code

Try a [HTTPURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (a simplified version of an example [found here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/java-how-read-from-url-string-text)):

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.elven.ee/ip/");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String myIp = content.toString();
```

Comment: it gives errors Unhandled exception type MalformedURLException and IOException :/

Comment: @Elven I see you've already selected the correct answer, but I've corrected my code so it should be working properly now.

Comment: Ok, thanks :). I'll try that out too. I can test and study from it as well!